# gcloud preview app run with logs no longer works?

Tags: gcloud

I couple of weeks ago I used to be able to run the local appengine preview with `--enable-mvm-logs` option

Now when I do that I get an error:

```
google.appengine.tools.docker.containers.ImageError: Image with tag google/appengine-log-server was not found
```

From reading elsewhere the image names have changed but it seems gcloud tool is still using old name?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, try running the following two commands:

```
$ docker pull gcr.io/google_appengine/log-processor
$ docker pull gcr.io/google_appengine/log-server
$ docker tag gcr.io/google_appengine/log-processor google/appengine-log-processor
$ docker tag gcr.io/google_appengine/log-server google/appengine-log-server
```